# sql запрос на удаление

Tags: sql, postgresql

База данных postgreSQL , есть две таблицы , "groups" (group_id (pk), name) - 6 строк и 
"students" (student_id(pk), group_id, first_name, last_name) - 43 строки.

Как удалить строки из таблицы "students" по конкретному названию (groups.name) из таблицы "groups"
На вот такой запрос

```
DELETE
FROM 
  public."GROUPS", 
  public."STUDENTS"
WHERE 
  "GROUPS"."GROUP_ID" = "STUDENTS"."GROUP_ID" AND "GROUPS"."NAME" = "SR-01";
```

пишет

> ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: ",")

на вот такой запрос

```
DELETE
FROM 
  public."STUDENTS"
WHERE 
  "GROUPS"."GROUP_ID" = "STUDENTS"."GROUP_ID" AND "GROUPS"."NAME" = "SR-01";
```

пишет

> таблица "GROUPS" отсутствует в предложении FROM

Comment: `FROM 
  public."GROUPS", 
JOIN  public."STUDENTS" ON "GROUPS"."GROUP_ID" = "STUDENTS"."GROUP_ID" WHERE 
  "GROUPS"."NAME" = "SR-01";`

Comment: такой запрос ругается на запятую перед JOIN , если ее убрать то ругается на JOIN !!!

Comment: да, постгрес, не заметил диалект. см. ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У PostgreSQL довольно забавный [синтаксис удаления](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-delete.html) с использованием ключевого слова `USING`:

```
DELETE FROM public."STUDENTS"
      USING public."GROUPS"
      WHERE "GROUPS"."GROUP_ID" = "STUDENTS"."GROUP_ID"
        AND "GROUPS"."NAME" = 'SR-01'
```

В крайнем случае всегда можно использовать старые, добрые подзапросы:

```
DELETE FROM public."STUDENTS"
 WHERE "STUDENTS"."GROUP_ID" IN(SELECT "GROUP_ID"
                                  FROM public."GROUPS"
                                 WHERE "NAME" = 'SR-01')
```

Comment: большое человеческое спасибо!!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE
FROM 
  public."STUDENTS"
  using public."groups"
WHERE 
  "GROUPS"."GROUP_ID" = "STUDENTS"."GROUP_ID" AND "GROUPS"."NAME" = "SR-01";
```

[фиддл](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/cb426/2)